# Chart options not used with chart js

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js, aurelia

I have a Aurelia project that uses chart js. I can display a chart fine but it seems that the chart options are not used.

I have a typescript controller that does the following:

```
SimpleLineData: LinearChartData;
optionschart: ChartSettings;

 activate() {

    this.optionschart = this.chartoptions;
    this.xx();
    setInterval(this.yy.bind(this), 1000);
}

public xx() {

      this.SimpleLineData  = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My First dataset 1",
                fillColor: '#9b0391',
                strokeColor: '#9b0391',
                pointColor: '#9b0391',
                pointStrokeColor: '#9b0391',
                pointHighlightFill: '#9b0391',
                pointHighlightStroke: '#9b0391',
                borderColor: "#9b0391",
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
            },
            {
                label: "My Second dataset 2",
                fillColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,0.2)',
                strokeColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
                pointColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
                pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
                pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
                borderColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
            }
        ]
    }
}

 public yy() {
    this.SimpleLineData.datasets[0].data[0] = this.x;
    this.x++;
}

public chartoptions = {
    animation: false
};
```

And in my html i do:

```
 <chart type="line" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; display: block;" should-update="true" throttle="1000" naive-options="optionschart" data.bind="SimpleLineData"></chart>
```

When `yy()` is called then the data is updated, but the chart renders again with the animation. Even when i have set the `animation: false` option.

Does anyone have a sugestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your html. `naive-options` should be changed to `native-options`. It still might not work because according to the [documentation](https://github.com/grofit/aurelia-chart#usage), it should be `native-options.bind`

Comment: That was the solution, including the bind. Many thanks.